# Integrating .jar file in Unity3D

Tags: java, c#, android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I have created a sample android project with a single acitivity of name "MainActivity", and I have created a simple static and a non-static functions in this activity. Then I converted this project into LibraryProject, so I found the jar file of this project in its bin folder. When I copy this .jar file and AndroidManifest.xml file in Unity's Assets/Plugins/Android folder. Neither the static nor non-static function is getting called.

```
using (AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    {
        using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        {
            obj_Activity .CallStatic("showMap");
        }
    }
```

Android Code is

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView mapView;
    String apiKey="AIzaSyA-CxbAb1fA7QLJEvq1eSCSvHq9zh1mgEI";
    static WebView view;
    static LinearLayout layout;
    public static Context context;
    static LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      layout = new LinearLayout(this);       
    setContentView(layout);
    context=this;
}


public static void showMap()
{
    Log.d("looter", "google.com");
     view=new WebView(context);
     view.setLayoutParams(params);


     view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           //  Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
         }

         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             //Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);

         }

         public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

         }
     });
     view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
     layout.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any log messages in eclipse when calling the function? I suspect either Unity will send a message saying it can't find the function or you'll get a log message from your function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue could be to do with this line:

```
using (AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
```

I suspect the class is returning the Unity class NOT your overridden class or it may be returning that class but saving the base class as it's value. Try finding your activity class by using your package id. e.g. com.yourcompanyname.yourClassName.